# Refresh UI when object key value change - Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

sorry for a noob question, just started with Knockout.js. I have an array of objects and I want to update the view when object property favorite: changes but every time I click on an icon that triggers the change nothing happens. When I add a new object to an array UI gets rerendered. I would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks

```
<div id="container" data-bind="foreach:savedSearches">
  <div class="save-search-item" data-bind="attr:{'data-name': $data.name, 'data-id':$data.id, 'favourite':$data.favorite() === 1}">
    <div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
    <div class="icons">
      <a href="#" class="favourite-search">
        <i class="fas fa-star" data-bind="css: {favourite: $data.favorite() === 1}"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="edit-search">
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="delete-search">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

var searches = [
    {
    activation_time: null,
    activation_time_ms: null,
    favourite: 1,
    enabled: 1,
    id: 66,
    name: "adfdfafs"
  },
  {
    activation_time: null,
    activation_time_ms: null,
    favourite: 0,
    enabled: 1,
    id: 66,
    name: "adfdfafs"
  }
];

ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel, $('#container'));

function AppViewModel(data) {
  self.savedSearches = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.favourite = ko.observable();

  self.populateSavedSearches = function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(search) {
      search.favorite = ko.observable();
    });

    self.savedSearches(data);
  }
}

$('.favourite-search').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // get parent element with id
  var parent = e.currentTarget.closest('.save-search-item');
  var searchId;
  var isFavourite = false;

  if (parent) {
    searchId = parseInt(parent.getAttribute('data-id'));
    isFavourite = parent.getAttribute('favourite');

    searches.map(function(search) {
      if (search.id === searchId) {
        search.favorite = 0;
        ko.populateSavedSearches(search);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using knockout, you should not add your own event listeners via jQuery.

In this case, use the `click` binding to react to user behavior.

I did the bare minimum to make your snippet work, but I think it gets the point across:

- You already found out you have to make the `favorite` property observable! Great start
- I added a `toggle` function to each of the searches that swaps the `favorite` observable between `1` and `0`
- In the *view*, I added a `click` binding that calls `toggle`
- In the *view*, I moved your `favourite` *attribute binding* to be a *css* binding. This makes sure favorited searches get the `favourite` class
- In CSS, I styled `.favourite` elements to have a yellow background.
- In `applyBindings`, I use `new` to create a new viewmodel and pass the app container using `[0]`

You can see these changes in action in the snippet below.

```js
var searches = [
    {
    activation_time: null,
    activation_time_ms: null,
    favourite: 1,
    enabled: 1,
    id: 66,
    name: "adfdfafs"
  },
  {
    activation_time: null,
    activation_time_ms: null,
    favourite: 0,
    enabled: 1,
    id: 66,
    name: "adfdfafs"
  }
];

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(searches), $('#container')[0]);

function AppViewModel(data) {
  const self = this;
  self.savedSearches = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.favourite = ko.observable();

  self.populateSavedSearches = function() {
    data.forEach(function(search) {
      search.favorite = ko.observable(search.favorite);
      search.toggle = function() {
        search.favorite(search.favorite() ? 0 : 1);
      }
    });

    self.savedSearches(data);
  }
  
  self.populateSavedSearches();
}
```

```css
.favourite { background: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="container" data-bind="foreach: savedSearches">
  <div class="save-search-item" data-bind="
    click: toggle,
    attr: {
      'data-name': $data.name,
      'data-id':$data.id
     },
     css: { 'favourite': $data.favorite() === 1 }
  ">
    <div data-bind="text: $data.name"></div>
    <div class="icons">
      <a href="#" class="favourite-search">
        <i class="fas fa-star" data-bind="css: {favourite: $data.favorite() === 1}"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="edit-search">
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="delete-search">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The thing is that I need to have the click event since when the favorite icon is clicked I have to call the database to set .save-search-item as favorite.

Comment: so when i make a call to make the search favourite i do ko.favourite(1) and to unset it ko.favourite(0) for the search with that ID, and then I call ko.populateSavedSearches(arrayOfAllSeraches) which changes the value but does not rerenders UI

Comment: Finally, it worked. I needed to do some minor modifications to your code but now it's working :D Thanks